# Are there ways to get modulated values similar to cyclic and negacyclic convolutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

The Wikipedia article on the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm states that there are methods that can get values modulo $a^n+1$ or $a^n-1$ for some value $a$.  More specifically, it [shows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm#Convolutions) that the [cyclic convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_convolution) yields values modulo $a^n-1$ and that the [negacyclic convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negacyclic_convolution) yields values modulo $a^n+1$.

Are there other similar methods of transforming values into different moduli?  I'm wondering if there are similar methods to those in the above links that can get products of something like values modulo $a^n+2$ or even modulo $a^n+c$ for some $c$.

Comment: Perhaps the convolutions stated above can be modified to give values modulo $a^n+c$...  It seems that in the examples given they either add or subtract $(4,13)$.  I wonder if adding $(4,13)$ again would give a value modulo $b^n-2$.